# Trying to dynamically increase height of UITableView while user adds rows to UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an app where the user is able to add rows to the UITableView dynamically.  This part is working fine.  However, on my iOS screen, the UITableView is of a static height regardless of how many rows there are.  Once the number of rows increases beyond a certain point, the user must scroll to see the additional cells.

What I would like to do is dynamically increase the height of the table with each row the user adds.  So for example, if I have a tableView, if the user adds one row, I would like the tableview to be 50px tall, if the user adds 2 rows, the table dynamically increases in height to 100px, until it reaches say, a maximum height of 250px. My code for adding the rows dynamically, is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender {

    NSString *theObjectToInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row #: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.tableData count]];
    [self.tableData addObject:theObjectToInsert];
    NSIndexPath *newPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.tableData.count-1 inSection:0];
    [self.choiceTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.choiceTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

How do I incorporate the dynamic growth of the UITableView along with the increasing number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, when you say the table height is statically set right now I'll assume that is not desired and you do want it to be dynamic.

What if recommend doing is every time you add a row, check the height of all of the rows already added. You can do that by calling methods already implemented in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
CGFloat maxDynamicTableHeight = 250.0f;

NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView];

CGFloat runningHeight = 0.0f;

for (int section = 0; section < numberOfSections && runningHeight < maxDynamicTableHeight; section++) {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self tableView:self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows && runningHeight < maxDynamicTableHeight; row++) {
        runningHeight += [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
    }
}

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = (runningHeight > maxDynamicTableHeight) ? maxDynamicTableHeight : runningHeight;
Self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

Sorry if there are any glaring issues, I'm on mobile so I can't test this right now.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  I'm trying to run your code, but I'm getting a runtime exception:*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc3ad185d0'  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your view controller implement the `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: Yes it does.  I implement both UITableViewDelegate, and UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Do you have `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your viewController?